# Pattern matching on same arm with different types

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I wonder if there is a way to simplify the following pattern match arms when two or more different enum's types have the same data member or same function.

(if not it will be nice to explain why)

### UPDATE:

as requested a more accurate example of what i want (forgive me for confusing data member access with function) ([try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c9f55be6f12a2218ab03de8eb366291)):

```
struct Point<T> {
    x: i32,
    y: T,
}

enum Record {
    V4(Point<i64>),
    V6(Point<i32>),
}

fn get_record() -> Record {
    Record::V4(Point{ x: 1, y: 1})
}

fn main() {
    let x = match get_record() {
        Record::V4(r) => r.x,
        Record::V6(r) => r.x,
    };
    println!("{}", &x);

    // this will not compile
    // let rec = get_record();
    // println!("{}", rec.x);

    // this will not compile either
    // note: if V4 Point was i32 it will compile & run
    // let rec = get_record();
    // let x = match get_record() {
    //     Record::V4(r) | Record::V6(r) => r.x,
    // };
}
```

## Original Post:

```
use std::net::IpAddr;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let v4_or_v6 = IpAddr::from_str("1.2.3.4").unwrap();

    // match expression, both arms only differ by 1 char
    let s = match v4_or_v6 {
        IpAddr::V4(ip) => ip.to_string(),
        IpAddr::V6(ip) => ip.to_string(),
    };
    println!("{}", &s);

    // not working:
    // let s2 = match v4_or_v6 {
    //     IpAddr::V4(ip) | IpAddr::V6(ip) => ip.to_string(),
    // };
    // println!("{}", &s2);
}
```

I understand that the underlying call to `to_string()` has different implementation for `Ipv4` than `Ipv6` but i think the compiler can be smart enough to handle this (am i wrong?)

trying to compile with the commented out code results in compilation error ([try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9c7055a8ba4bb83e628a43dd9b4c91d)):

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:37
   |
16 |         IpAddr::V4(ip) | IpAddr::V6(ip) => ip.to_string(),
   |                                     ^^ expected struct `std::net::Ipv4Addr`, found struct `std::net::Ipv6Addr`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::net::Ipv4Addr`
              found type `std::net::Ipv6Addr`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: Could not compile `playground`.
```

Comment: You can simply use `let s = v4_or_v6.to_string();`, since `IpAddr` have implement of `Display`.

Comment: thanks but my use case is more complex than this and i need to use pattern match. ill try simplify the case and edit this although its good to know its possible

Comment: Then please provide a real mcve and will reflect your usecase.

Comment: If what you want is not to repeat the arm body, you can use a macro [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=916d68105477238e22aaddc50940488c).

Comment: @hellow ive reflected my usecase twice, i did not understood that struct member vs trait really different here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working code de-sugars to:

```
let s = match v4_or_v6 {
    IpAddr::V4(ip) => <Ipv4Addr as ToString>::to_string(&ip),
    IpAddr::V6(ip) => <Ipv6Addr as ToString>::to_string(&ip),
};
```

Even though the statements look the same, they are different functions and in each branch it is known statically which `to_string` is going to be used. To get this to work in a single match arm, you would have to somehow produce a trait object from the pattern match, so that each `ip` has the same type (i.e. `&dyn ToString`). Currently there isn't a way to do that and I haven't seen any proposal like it.

It's pretty common to see identical-looking match arms, where the same trait method is called on each, even in the `rustc` project. This is just how it is, for now.

---

If you have an `enum` where each variant holds types that implement the same traits, it might be convenient to implement the traits on the `enum` and delegate to the inner types. If you don't have a trait but your types have common structure (as in the `x`, `y` fields in the struct of your updated post), then you can provide an accessor on the `enum`:

```
impl Record {
    fn x(&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Record::V4(Point { x, .. }) => *x,
            Record::V6(Point { x, .. }) => *x,
        }
    }
}
```

While this is basically the same thing, it means you can write it once instead of everywhere that you need to access `x`:

```
let rec = get_record();
let x = get_record().x();
```

Note that `IpAddr` already does this so, in your original code, you could have avoided the `match` altogether with:

```
let s = v4_or_v6.to_string();
```

Comment: ok thanks, can you try answer the second updated example? is it possible to access data member of enum containing multiple types?